# How to select rows based on conditions applied to the columns and use that to create another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have my input data as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Pillar": ["block", "segment", "block", "block", "segment",
              "segment", "block",  "block", "block"],
    "Pillar ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1],
    "Distance" : [1.5, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7.8, 9, 3, 6]
})
 df
#   Pillar    Pillar ID     Distance
# 0 Block       1             1.5
# 1 Segment     1             3
# 2 Block       1             4
# 3 Block       2             5
# 4 Segment     2             7 
# 5 Segment     3             7.8 
# 6 Block       2             9
# 7 Block       1             3
# 8 Block       1             6
```

I want an output to get all the "Block" with two consecutive equal "Pillar ID" and assign "start" to
the block with the lesser distance among the two consecutive blocks with same ID and assign
"stop" to the block with the greater distance among the two consecutive blocks with same ID to
have an output as below:

```
#   Pillar    Pillar ID     Distance   Position
# 0 Block       1             1.5      Start
# 2 Block       1             4        Stop
# 3 Block       2             5        Start 
# 6 Block       2             9        Stop
# 7 Block       1             3        Start
# 8 Block       1             6        Stop
```

Comment: Your definition of "*consecutive*" is unclear

Comment: Why is the row with Pillar ID 3 ignored? Shouldn't that mean the Stop of Pilliar ID 2 be 7 instead of 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below code:

```
df.sort_values(['Pillar'], inplace=True)

df['Pillar ID_Shift'] =  (df['Pillar ID'] != df.groupby(['Pillar'])['Pillar ID'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Position'] = np.where(df['Distance'] == df.groupby(['Pillar','Pillar ID_Shift'])['Distance'].transform('min'), 'Start', 'Stop')
df[df['Pillar'] == 'block'][['Pillar', 'Pillar ID', 'Distance', 'Position']]
```

Output:

[image]